# View Data Not Working Correctly In MVC 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp-classic

Well  i m quite new to mvc n i have been one hell of the problem here. I want to pass data from action method using ViewData to my view. I m using Asp.net MVC 2.0 with visual studio 2008.I know how to use view data from  an action method & using it in a view.

```
Here is what i have written in my action method : - 

             public ActionResult Index()
                    {
                        NorthWindEntities db = new NorthWindEntities();
                        var data = (from id in db.Orders
                                    join ordid in db.Order_Details on id.OrderID equals                  ordid.OrderID
                                    select new
                                    {
                                        orderid = id.OrderID,
                                        productid = ordid.ProductID,
                                        discount = ordid.Discount
                                    }
                                      );
                        ViewData["Data"] = data;
                        return View();
                    }
```

and here is the code in the view : -

```
        <%foreach (var item in (IEnumerable)ViewData["Data"] )
          {
              Response.Write(item.orderId);

          } %>
```

It is giving an error like this..

> 'object' does not contain a definition for 'orderId' and no extension
>   method 'orderId' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Find out what ViewData["Data"] really is by outputting ViewData["Data"].GetType().FullName

Comment: Check it ViewData["products"] having data.Debug the controller.

Comment: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[<>f__AnonymousType1`3[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Single, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], MvcApplication1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following (it's kind of best practice to use a viewmodel... create a class OrderViewModel, then populate that with your select new OrderViewModel like so...

```
namespace MyApp.ViewModels
{
    public class OrderViewModel
    {
        public int OrderId { get; set; }

        public int ProductId { get; set; }

        public int Discount { get; set; }
    }
}

public ActionResult Index()
{
    NorthWindEntities db = new NorthWindEntities();

    List<OrderViewModel> data = (from id in db.Orders
                                join ordid in db.Order_Details on id.OrderID equals ordid.OrderID
                                select new OrderViewModel()
                                {
                                    OrderId = id.OrderID,
                                    ProductId = ordid.ProductID,
                                    Discount = ordid.Discount
                                }).ToList();

    ViewData["Data"] = data;
    return View();
```

and then in your view page...

```
@using MyApp.ViewModels

<%foreach (var item in (List<OrderViewModel>)ViewData["Data"] )
{
    Response.Write(item.orderId);
}%>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to take one view model as below :-

```
public class ViewModelClass
{
     public int OrderId{ get; set; }
     public int ProductId{ get; set; }
     public int Discount{ get; set; }
}
```

and in controller :-

```
  public ActionResult Index()
                    {
                        NorthWindEntities db = new NorthWindEntities();
                        var data = (from id in db.Orders
                                    join ordid in db.Order_Details on id.OrderID equals                  ordid.OrderID
                                    select new ViewModelClass
                                    {
                                        orderid = id.OrderID,
                                        productid = ordid.ProductID,
                                        discount = ordid.Discount
                                    }
                                      );
                        ViewData["Data"] = data;
                        return View();
                    }
```

and in view :-

```
 <%foreach (var item in (ViewData["Data"] as List<ViewModelClass>))
          {
              Response.Write(item.orderId);

          } %>
```

Comment: i really appreciate ur ans neel but now it is giving object null error

Comment: object null where @NitinSingh?

Comment: it is saying that viewdata is null but whilw debuging i can see the data in the ViewData Object In the action  method

Comment: are you in the same view as attached with that particular action method @NitinSingh?

Comment: Try forgetting ViewData and return the ViewModelClass... in your controller action return View(data) and then in your view something like @model ViewModelClass then in your foreach just use (var item in Model)